# why won't the function put the words inside the list?

Tags: python

i'm trying to make an function where you put in an list of words and it returns the ones that start with an A/a.
i have this code:

```
def findA(words):
  wordslist=[]
  for x in words:
    if x[0]=="a" or x[0]=="A":
      wordslist.append[x]
  return wordslist
print(findA(wordlist))
```

and it gives me this error when i run it:

```
File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
print(findA(wordlist))
File "main.py",line 6, in findA
wordslist.append[x]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

i have tinkered with it but could not figure out what was wrong with it.

Comment: It is a method/function. Use `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: [Here's](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/PiercingDisgustingEngines) a working version based on @r0ei's suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`append` is a function and takes only one argument. I use list comprehension and I check if the first character in `x` is in a list which containes `'A'` or `'a'`.

Try the following.

```
def findA(words: list) -> list:
    return [x for x in words if x[0] in ['A', 'a']]

print(findA(['a', 'b']))
```

Comment: @lazerlegendys If my answer helped you, think about accepting it.

Comment: how do you do that?(sorry i just started using this website)

Comment: @lazerlegendys To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

How does your variable wordlist looks like?